# How to edit PDF using Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

While it's easy to generate a pdf from HTML document. What about editing and saving an existing PDF file. Chrome can open pdf files and lets you edit them. Can you do that with puppeteer? If yes how.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in puppeteer. Puppeteer generates PDFs using the "Print to PDF" tool.
But the PDF viewer Chrome uses it's not a target (tab) puppeteer can automate because there is no devtools involved.